# Diferença no true e false na função header('Location: ') no PHP

Tags: php, header

Estava lendo alguns artigos sobre redirecionamento de página com a função header(), e me deparei com dois exemplos para usar a função:
1)

```
<?php     
header('Location: endereço', **true**, 301);  
exit();  
?>
```

2)

```
<?php     
header('Status: 301 Moved Permanently', **false**, 301);  
header('Location: endereço');  
exit();  
?>
```

Testei os dois exemplos e ambos funcionaram, mas não encontrei um explicação da diferencia do false para o true depois do "[...]endereço',". Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 4):

O `true` e `false`, que está alterando, é o `Replace`, [segundo a documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.header.php):

```
header ( string $header [, bool $replace = TRUE [, int $http_response_code ]] ) : void
```

O que nos importa é a definição do `$replace`:

> **Replace:**
> The optional replace parameter indicates whether the header should replace a previous similar header, or add a second header of the same type. By default it will replace, but if you pass in FALSE as the second argument you can force multiple headers of the same type.

---

Quando ele é `true` (e é o valor padrão) ele irá substituir o cabeçalho, enquanto que se estiver como `false` não será substituído o valor, por exemplo:

```
header('Location: https://google.com');
header('Location: https://bing.com');
```

Isto deve resultar em apenas um único header `Location: https://bing.com`, isso porque o `https://bing.com` substitui o `https://google.com`. Entretanto, se estiver como `false`:

```
header('Location: https://google.com', false);
header('Location: https://bing.com', false);
```

Isto deve apresentar os dois headers, não apenas o último. Isso porque o `false` não irá substituir.

---

Entretanto, o `Location` não pode aparecer múltiplas vezes num mesmo cabeçalho. Ao menos, no [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2.2):

> A sender MUST NOT generate multiple header fields with the same field
> name in a message unless either the entire field value for that
> header field is defined as a comma-separated list [i.e., #(values)]
> or the header field is a well-known exception (as noted below).

O `Location` não é dessas uma exceções e não pode apresentar listas. Já o `Set-Cookies` é uma exceção, por exemplo. O `WWW-Authenticate` é uma lista, portanto também pode ser dividido entre vários headers individuais. Considerando o `Set-Cookies`, por ser comum, numa mesma requisição pode receber vários `Set-Cookies` num mesmo cabeçalho. Então, este seria um cenário onde utilizaria o `false` no `header()`, porque se usar o `true` (padrão) apenas um `Set-Cookie` iria existir.

---